# Any sense in marking an IUnknown-derived interface as dual in IDL?

Tags: windows, com, com-interop, idl, midl

Reviewing our code I've found a curious definition in one of .idl files:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(uuidhere),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    oleautomation,
    hidden
]
interface IOurInterface : IUnknown {
    //methods here
};
```

How can an interface derived directly from `IUnknown` possibly be a dual interface? Will anything break if I remove the `dual` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720689/how-does-com-select-how-to-marshal-an-interface/1741721#1741721) to another question concerning marshaling [user voyce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1719/voyce) points to [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0199/com/com0199.aspx) that basically states the following:

When any interface (IDispatch-derived or not) is marked either `dual` or `oleautomation` (or both) it is treated specially when `RegisterTypeLib()` is invoked (which is typically done by DllRegisterServer). For each such interface an HKCR\Interface{InterfaceId} key is created under which {00020424-0000-0000-C0000-000000000046} class is referenced as proxy/stub. This class id corresponds to typelib marshaller also known as oleautomation marshaller.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Since you already had `oleautomation` I figured that was implicit... I didn't know the exact specifics, though, so thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: And I still think you should make sure the object doesn't currently respond to QI for `IDispatch` before you remove it.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree about the QI responce with IDispatch.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason that that would work, given the docs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366807(VS.85).aspx

> Interfaces identified by the dual
>   attribute must be compatible with
>   Automation and be derived from
>   IDispatch. This attribute is not
>   allowed on dispinterfaces.

It could be that the `[dual]` attribute implicitly adds `IDispatch` to the interface.

What you could do is check the code implementing the interface (assuming this is ATL) if it derives from `IDispatchImpl`. If so, it actually responds to QI for `IDispatch` and might be used as such.

Another alternative is to instantiate an object implementing `IOurInterface` and QI it for `IDispatch` -- if it succeeds, you probably can't remove it.

Actually, come to think of it, maybe `[dual]` doesn't technically require that you derive from `IDispatch` as long as you implement both your custom interface and `IDispatch`?